# apache location directive spanning virtual hosts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a simple question.

In my environment there is a apache configured like this.

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
        ServerAdmin a@example.com
        DocumentRoot /apps/docroot/
        ServerName server.mydomain.tld
        <Location /report >
                ProxyPass http://report.mydomain.tld/
                ProxyPassReverse http://report.mydomain.tld/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.11:443>
         ServerAdmin a@example.com
        DocumentRoot /apps/docroot/
        ServerName server.mydomain.tld
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite !EXP1024-RC4-SHA:!EXP1024-DES-CBC-SHA:ALL:!ADH:!EXP56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/crt.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/crt.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/CA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The question is, will the proxy settings apply to the SSL vhost? (I.E If i access /report using https, Will the request still get proxied).. I know it will get proxied if i use http..

-Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't.  The directives within one virtual host only apply to that host.

If you have a set of directives that you want to apply repeatedly in multiple vhost/location/directory contexts, the best way to do that is to put them into a separate file, and [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) them in each context where they're needed.